# How to access and/or modify the (sql)DataSource in code behind (ASP.net c#)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

To connect to my database I used the wizard to make SQLDataSource. But I need to access it in code behind, to store my data in the database. Does someone knows how I can do that?

I appreciate your help. This is the code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource 

ID="MySqlDataSource" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:HELPDESK_OUTLOOKConnectionString3 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT 

hd_aanvraag_fase.aanvraag_id,

hd_statussen.status_omschrijving as status,

hd_melding_niveau_1.niveau_omschrijving AS niveau1_omschrijving,

aanvrager.werknemersnaam AS melder ,

hd_aanvragen.aanvraag_titel ,

hd_aanvragen.aanvraag_omschrijving,

hd_aanvraag_fase.fase_datum

FROM hd_aanvragen 

INNER JOIN hd_meldingen         ON hd_meldingen.melding_id      =  hd_aanvragen.melding_id

INNER JOIN hd_melding_niveau_1  ON  hd_melding_niveau_1.niveau1_id = hd_meldingen.niveau1_id

INNER JOIN hd_melding_niveau_2  ON  hd_melding_niveau_2.niveau2_id = hd_meldingen.niveau2_id

INNER JOIN hd_aanvraag_fase     ON hd_aanvraag_fase.aanvraag_id =  hd_aanvragen.aanvraag_id

INNER JOIN hd_statussen         ON hd_statussen.status_id     =  hd_aanvraag_fase.status_id

INNER JOIN  hd_werknemers AS oplosser    ON oplosser.werknemer_Id    =  hd_aanvraag_fase.werknemer_Id

INNER JOIN hd_werknemers  AS aanvrager    ON aanvrager.werknemer_Id    =  hd_aanvragen.werknemer_Id

WHERE hd_statussen.status_id = 15

ORDER BY hd_aanvragen.aanvraag_id ,  hd_statussen.status_id"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: If you can post some of your code then we may understand more of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you need to get the SQLDS data in something like a DataTable to see on code your data? or you just need to get data back on the DB?

Although I give you two useful links that can help you out in both situations:

1) http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/7333-How-Extract-data-from-SQLDataSource-Data.aspx

```
DataView dv = new DataView();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dv = mySQLDataSource.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty) as DataView;
dt = dv.ToTable();
```

now on dt you have your data

2) http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/SqlDataSource10032008142537PM/SqlDataSource.aspx

Working with sqldatasource on .net 3.5

Hope that can help

Comment: I use a gridview and to display data in the gridview, I used the wizard to make my SqlDataSource. Now I need to know how I can access/modify SqlDataSource programmatically.

Comment: dv = (System.Data.DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(System.Web.UI.DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);

Answer (score 1):

If you give the datasource an ID, in the markup code:

```
<SqlDataSource ID="MyDatasource" .../>
```

you should be able to access it from code behind.

Comment: To "store data in database" using your SqlDataSource, you need to deifine an UpdateCommand, just like you did a SelectCommand. Check: http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/inserting-updating-and-deleting-data-with-the-sqldatasource-cs and scroll down just below Figure 8 where they have an example for this. (A good read for more info on SqlDataSource.)

Comment: But I ask you how to modify SqlDataSource programmatically.